# Pandas - Keep the first n characters where n is defined in the column N

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, delimiter

I have a DataFrame from a source where the names are repeated back to back without a delimiter to split upon.

Example:

```
In [1] 
data = {"Names": ["JakeJake", "ThomasThomas", "HarryHarry"],
       "Scores": [70, 81, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Out [1]

    Names       Scores
0   JakeJake        70
1   ThomasThomas    81
2   HarryHarry      23
```

I would like a method to keep just the first half of the 'Names' column. My initial thought was to  do the following:

```
In [2]
df["N"] = df["Names"].str.len()//2
df["X"] = df["Names"].str[:df["N"]]
```

However this gives the output

```
Out [2]

Names             Scores N    X
0   JakeJake         70  4  nan
1   ThomasThomas     81  6  nan
2   HarryHarry       23  5  nan
```

The desired output would be

```
Out [2]

Names            Scores N        X
0   JakeJake        70  4   Jake
1   ThomasThomas    81  6   Thomas
2   HarryHarry      23  5   Harry
```

I'm sure the answer will be something simple but I can't get my head around it. Cheers

Comment: are the names always in camel case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on column `Names`, as follows:

```
df['X'] = df['Names'].map(lambda x: x[:len(x)//2])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

          Names  Scores       X
0      JakeJake      70    Jake
1  ThomasThomas      81  Thomas
2    HarryHarry      23   Harry
```

Comment: much faster than regex (of mine), thanks for the solution.

Comment: Thanks @MustafaAydın  I personally also like using regex but recently also encountered a question that needs to compare the performance of with and without regex and also found solution without regex is likely to run faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` on `Names` column, then take only the part of the required string.

```py
>>> df.assign(x=df['Names'].apply(lambda x: x[:len(x)//2]))

          Names  Scores       x
0      JakeJake      70    Jake
1  ThomasThomas      81  Thomas
2    HarryHarry      23   Harry
```

Comment: much faster than regex (of mine), thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

With a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/QXxYko/1) to extract names and `str.len` for the lengths:

```
df["X"] = df.Names.str.extract(r"^(.+)\1$")
df["N"] = df.X.str.len()
```

where regex looks for a fullmatch of anything repeated 2 times (`\1` refers to the first capturing group within the regex).

```
>>> df

          Names  Scores       X  N
0      JakeJake      70    Jake  4
1  ThomasThomas      81  Thomas  6
2    HarryHarry      23   Harry  5
```

Answer (score 0):

use a regex to split the camel case, we can set the rule to split any uppercase letter that is immediately followed by a lower case letter

```
 n = df['Names'].str.split('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])',expand=True)[0]
 df['N'], df['X'] = n, n.str.len()
```

---

```
print(df)

          Names  Scores       N  X
0      JakeJake      70    Jake  4
1  ThomasThomas      81  Thomas  6
2    HarryHarry      23   Harry  5
```